# Find next array index not from start AND if not found loop from beginning

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const arr = [{item:'a', value:false}, {item:'b', value:true}, {item:'c', value:true}, {item:'d', value:false}];
const startIndex = 2;
```

Given startIndex find next object in array with value=true.
Iteration must be forward and, if not found, start from index 0.
Should return arr[1];

I've just hit the wall and seems can't find an iteration method:/

```
let result = {};
for (let i = startIndex + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!arr[i] && i < arr.length) {
        result = arr[i];
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: There is this function called `indexOf` it takes 2 parameters... look it up

Comment: @Akxe, this does only work with same object references.

Comment: Hint: You aren't checking the `value` property and not breaking if found

Comment: How do I start from the beginning when I reach end. Given for loop

Comment: Just use 2 loops: the first one from `startIndex + 1` forward, if not found start the second one from 0 to `startIndex`. Why do you want it to be 1 loop?

Comment: @Yuri. Never had to deal with that kind of case. Just thought there might be a way. I will try double loop. Thanks for idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single loop and take `startIndex` as offset and shape the index by the remainder with the length.

```js
const
    array = [{ item: 'a', value: false }, { item: 'b', value: true }, { item: 'c', value: true }, { item: 'd', value: false }],
    startIndex = 3;
    
let result;

for (let i = startIndex; i < array.length + startIndex; i++) {
    console.log(i, i % array.length);
    if (array[i % array.length].value) {
        result = array[i % array.length];
        break;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: let i = startIndex + 1; produced desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood. But...

```js
getNext = function(startIndex, arr){
    var i;
    for(i = startIndex; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].value){
            return arr[i];
        }
    }

    if(startIndex != 0){
        return getNext(0, arr);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This works! But you have an error "i > arr.length" should be "i < arr.length". Thank you.

Comment: Yes! That's true XD Edited!

Comment: Great solution. But I would like to avoid recursion if possible.

Comment: Only one level of recursivity. You will not have a stack overflow at all.

Comment: I agree with you. But I prefer to keep recursion only for cases when there is a recursive data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.splice` to create the two halves:

- First, search for the element with `value=true` in the second half, if found, keep in mind to add the length of the first to the `index`
- If not found in the second part, search in the first one

```js
const getElementAtIndexFromStart = (arr=[], startIndex=0) => {
  // get index of element if exists starting from startIndex
  let index = arr.slice(startIndex+1).findIndex(({value}) => value===true);
  if(index!==-1) {
    // if found, add the start index to it to represent the position in in arr
    index = index + startIndex + 1;
  } else {
    // if not found in the second half, search in the first one
    index = arr.slice(0, startIndex+1).findIndex(({value}) => value===true);
  }
  return arr[index];
}

const arr = [{item:'a', value:false}, {item:'b', value:true}, {item:'c', value:true}, {item:'d', value:false}];

console.log('Start: 0 => ', getElementAtIndexFromStart(arr, 0));
console.log('Start: 1 => ', getElementAtIndexFromStart(arr, 1));
console.log('Start: 2 => ', getElementAtIndexFromStart(arr, 2));
console.log('Start: 3 => ', getElementAtIndexFromStart(arr, 3));
console.log('Start: 5 => ', getElementAtIndexFromStart(arr, 5));
```

Comment: Unless I am misreading something. It should return startIndex=0 -> arr[1]; si=1-> arr[2]; si=2 -> arr[0]; si=3-> arr[0]. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: @TadasV. so element at ``startIndex`` shouldn't be count? (si=1-> arr[2] instead of arr[1] - si=2 -> arr[0] instead of arr[2])

Comment: Should be: f(arr,0)=arr[1], f(arr,1)=arr[2], f(arr,2)=arr[0], f(arr,3)=arr[0]

Comment: But ``arr[0]`` has ``value=false``

Comment: Should be: f(arr,0)=arr[1], f(arr,1)=arr[2], f(arr,2)=arr[1], f(arr,3)=arr[1]

Comment: Or Should be: f(arr,0)=b, f(arr,1)=c, f(arr,2)=b, f(arr,3)=b

Comment: Yes I updated the answer, first half is now ``[0, startIndex]`` and the second is ``]startIndex,length-1]``